# Serving express static files not working with bundle from webpack :(

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

so I have a node/express app that serves back a bundle.js bundled by webpack.

I've been banging my head at this issue for close to 4 nights and I don't know anymore.

I'm getting the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error as the express static middleware is not catching the request and treating it.

webpack.config.js:

```
output: {
   path: BUILD_DIR,
   filename: 'bundle.js',
   // https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/issues/205
   // DO NOT leave publicPath out -- it'll cause errors if we do
   publicPath: '/',
},
```

express middleware:

```
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
app.use(serveStatic(
   path.join(__dirname, 'statics'),
))
app.use('/dist', express.static('dist'));
app.use('/statics', express.static('statics'));\
```

index.html:
    `<script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: thank you @Tomasz for helping edit.

Comment: I know it's a late reply but you should let express use your publicPath to serve static file. Like `app.use('/', express.static('dist')); I was tyring to understand this for a long time.. As far as i understand, All files emitted by webpack reference webpack's publicPath thus server should handle this path properly.

Comment: @godsenal thank you so much. I guess I missed it elsewhere. But your comment saved the day!